# Datagridview Datagridcheckbox cell values not matching GUI

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a unbound DataGridView with 6 columns, the first being a DataGridCheckBoxColumn. When a user clicks on a checkbox cell, I want to determine what cells have been checked and what ones are not. Here is my code:

```
private void UpdateSelectedPlaces()
{
    //Clear out the places list each time the user selects a new item (or items)
    _selectedPlaces.Clear();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in placesGridView.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[0].Value.Equals(true))
        {
            _selectedPlaces.Add((TripPlace)row.DataBoundItem);
        }
    }
}
//Click event handler
private void placesGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateSelectedPlaces();
}
```

**I am finding that the DataGridCheckBoxCells are not holding the correct value at the time of the click**. This occurs for all rows. There seems to be no pattern really. I was hoping that the event was just not called at the right time (I.e. the checking of the checkbox was yet to be completed) but I cannot prove that.

**In short, even though the GUI displays a checked checkbox, the back end thinks the checkbox is not checked when using `.Value`** Is there a simpler way to just determine if each cell[0] is checked or not checked in a datagridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am finding that the DataGridCheckBoxCells are not holding the
>   correct value at the time of the click.

This is normal and by design because you are using `DataGridView.CellContentClick` event. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Use this event to detect button clicks for a *DataGridViewButtonCell* or
>   link clicks for a *DataGridViewLinkCell*. 
> For clicks in a
>   *DataGridViewCheckBoxCell*, ***this event occurs before the check box
>   changes value***, so if you do not want to calculate the expected value
>   based on the current value, you will typically handle the
>   *DataGridView.CellValueChanged* event instead. Because that event occurs
>   only when the user-specified value is committed, which typically
>   occurs when focus leaves the cell, you must also handle the
>   *DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged* event.

The corrected code is similar to the other answer but unfortunately, the reason of the *problem* was not explained in that answer.

```
private void UpdateSelectedPlaces()
{
    //Clear out the places list each time the user selects a new item (or items)
    _selectedPlaces.Clear();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in placesGridView.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[0].Value.Equals(true))
        {
            _selectedPlaces.Add((TripPlace)row.DataBoundItem);
        }
    }
}


private void placesGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateSelectedPlaces();
    }

private void placesGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (placesGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        placesGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void placesGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Boolean bl;

    if (placesGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "name of check column")
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)placesGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2]; //2 number of check column

        //bl is the check box current condition.
        //Change only this in your list eg list[e.RowIndex] = bl; No need to check all rows.
        bl = (Boolean)checkCell.Value; 

    }
}

private void placesGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (placesGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        placesGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }

}
```